# Exchange FindsItems return tasks

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a c# app with .net framework 4.7 working. I read that .net Framework will be replaced with .net Core, .net Standard so I wanted to move it to .net core 3.1

Surprisingly, to get emails from exchange online the example that one can find everywhere
"foreach (EmailMessage email in exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100))"
does not work, returning VS CS1579 error
"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'type1' because 'type2' does not contain a public definition for 'identifier'"

Of course, exchange.FindItems type is "(awaitable) System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FindItemsResults>"

Looking at dozens of examples, I always find the same examples not using Tasks, so I do not find an example to make this works,

- is this new return type "Task" correct because of net core ?
- how can I implement this new type ?

Thanks
Olivier

Comment: `await exchange.FindItems(`

Comment: *so I wanted to move it to .net core 3.1* - EOL's less than a year away, btw - it graduated into being .NET 6 already

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I tried this but I get  message 'the await operator can only be used with an async method"
Not sure my solution is the correct one, I used 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<FindItemsResults<Item>> tasks= exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "*",new ItemView(100));
var getawait = tasks.GetAwaiter();
while (!getawait.IsCompleted) { Thread.Sleep(1000); }
var result = tasks.Result;
 foreach (EmailMessage email in result)...